# Container up and running - unable to serve files in web-browser - Docker

Tags: docker

My container is up an running successfully - i'm on a MacOS Catalina;

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                      NAMES
487b211c7300        laravel-demo_laravel-app   "docker-php-entrypoi…"   6 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds        9000/tcp, 9021/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8021->80/tcp   laravel-app
```

My `docker-compose.yml` looks like;

```
version: '3'
services:

#Laravel App
laravel-app:
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
container_name: laravel-app
restart: unless-stopped
tty: true
environment:
  SERVICE_NAME: laravel-app
  SERVICE_TAGS: dev
working_dir: /var/www/html
ports:
  - 8021:80
volumes:
  - ./:/var/www/html
```

and my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/html/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Install Additional dependencies
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache \
 build-base shadow vim curl \
 php7 \
 php7-fpm \
 php7-common \
 php7-pdo \
 php7-pdo_mysql \
 php7-mysqli \
 php7-mcrypt \
 php7-mbstring \
 php7-xml \
 php7-openssl \
 php7-json \
 php7-phar \
 php7-zip \
 php7-gd \
 php7-dom \
 php7-session \
 php7-zlib

# Add and Enable PHP-PDO Extenstions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql

# Install PHP Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin -- 
filename=composer

# Remove Cache
RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

# Add UID '1000' to www-data
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data
RUN usermod -u 501 www-data

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www/html

# Change current user to www
USER www-data
```

These two files are both on the root of my fresh Laravel install.

Internal/external ports look fine in my config and with `docker ps` reporting success - my app should launch in a browser no? In theory - I should see the Laravel splash-screen;-

[image]

Well, unfortunately it doesn't and it's kicking my ass.

Things I've tried;

```
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm", "--host", "http://localhost"]
```

and

```
#CMD ["php-fpm", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Plus, various implementations of `docker-compose.yml` - like removing the `environment:` parameter - but no joy.

By comparing my `Dockerfile` & `docker-compose.yml` - are you able to offer some clues?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you cant beat em - join em;-

https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/laravel